# Horizontal or vertical database layout and database performance

Tags: mysql, database

I'm building a database that's processes astronomical type data for over 4000 cities based on specific dates in time.

There's around 70 fields of data for every city including things like planet longitude etc.

I'm not sure whether to build this database horizontally with one main table with lots of specific field catagory like the following:

**Option1**

[image]

Or create separate tables for each field like the following (both of these examples are using the same example data)

**Option 2**

[image]

What attracts me to Option 1, is that there will be a lot less rows in the database. So for one date, there will be 4000 rows since that's how many cities there are. However, with option 2, one date will produce over 200,000 rows. So for say, 100 dates, the difference is from 400,000 rows to 20 million rows... which seems like far too much?

The disandvantages of Option 1 are that it would seem to be more tedious to create the sql table and I'd have to specify the length of delimited fields, which I'm not 100% sure about.

What's would be the best practice here in determining the database layout and does the final amount of rows actually matter in terms of size and query time? Bearing in mind I will only be create queries based on city ids, which will pull a maximum of 4000 rows per query.

Comment: What is the problem with option 1 regarding the delimited fields?

Comment: I've just heard that it's bad practice to have delimited fields, and also I'd have to preset the size of the fields to the maximum size possible size for that dataset

Comment: Well the data has to be somewhere.  I don't see how you avoid the field width problem in option 2.

Comment: So would you say option 2 is better than 1?

Comment: Option 2 looks very verbose, over-normalized, and seems that it would tough to work with.  So I vote for option 1.

Comment: Thanks, I was beginning to lean in that direction too